# Cocos2d html5 tutorial return blank page

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to do this tutorial : [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2013/05/16/from-zero-to-a-complete-game-with-cocos2d-html5-step-1/)

Here's my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Circle Chain Cocos2d HTML5 version</title>
       <script src="cocos2d.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:white">
       <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
   </body>
</html>
```

cocos2ds.js :

```
(function () {
var d = document;
var c = {
    menuType:"canvas",
        COCOS2D_DEBUG:2, // full debug mode
    box2d:false, // no physics in this game
    chipmunk: false, // no chipmunk engine
    showFPS:true, // let's show the FPS meter
    frameRate:60, // 60 frames per second
    tag:"gameCanvas", // id of the canvas element
    engineDir:"../cocos2d/", // path to your cocos2d installation
    appFiles:["circlechain.js"] // path to the main game file
};
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var s = d.createElement("script");
    s.src = c.engineDir + "platform/jsloader.js";
    d.body.appendChild(s);
    s.c = c;
    s.id = "cocos2d-html5";
    document.ccConfig = c;
});
})();
```

main.js :

```
var cocos2dApp = cc.Application.extend({
config:document.ccConfig,
ctor:function (scene) {
    this._super();
    this.startScene = scene;
    cc.COCOS2D_DEBUG = this.config["COCOS2D_DEBUG"];
        cc.initDebugSetting();
    cc.setup(this.config["tag"]);
    cc.Loader.getInstance().onloading = function () {
        cc.LoaderScene.shareLoaderScene().draw();
    };
    cc.Loader.getInstance().onload = function () {
        cc.AppController.shareAppController().didFinishLaunchingWithOptions();
    };
    cc.Loader.getInstance().preload([
    ]);
},
applicationDidFinishLaunching:function () {
    var director = cc.Director.getInstance();
    director.setDisplayStats(this.config["showFPS"]);
    director.setAnimationInterval(1.0 / this.config["frameRate"]);
    director.runWithScene(new this.startScene());
    return true;
}
});     
var myApp = new cocos2dApp(circlechain);
```

circlechain.js :

```
var circlechain = cc.Scene.extend({
onEnter:function(){
    this._super();
    var layer = new circleChainGame();
    layer.init();
    this.addChild(layer);
}
})

var circleChainGame = cc.Layer.extend({
init:function(){
    this._super();
    var circleSpeed = 2;
    var s = cc.Director.getInstance().getWinSize();
    var gameLayer = cc.LayerColor.create(new cc.Color4B(0, 0, 0, 255), 500, 500)
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        var greenCircle = cc.Sprite.create("greencircle.png");
        var randomDir = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
        greenCircle.xSpeed=circleSpeed*Math.cos(randomDir);
        greenCircle.ySpeed=circleSpeed*Math.sin(randomDir);
        gameLayer.addChild(greenCircle);
        greenCircle.setPosition(new cc.Point(Math.random()*500,Math.random()*500));
        greenCircle.schedule(function(){
             this.setPosition(new cc.Point(this.getPosition().x+this.xSpeed,this.getPosition().y+this.ySpeed));
             if(this.getPosition().x>500){
                this.setPosition(new cc.Point(this.getPosition().x-500,this.getPosition().y));
            }
            if(this.getPosition().x<0){
                this.setPosition(new cc.Point(this.getPosition().x+500,this.getPosition().y));
            }
            if(this.getPosition().y>500){
                this.setPosition(new cc.Point(this.getPosition().x ,this.getPosition().y-500));
            }
            if(this.getPosition().y<0){
                this.setPosition(new cc.Point(this.getPosition().x ,this.getPosition().y+500));
            }
        })
    }
     this.addChild(gameLayer);
    return true;
}
});
```

But all i see is a blank page.

I'm on a mac, and i'm already using MAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried this tutorial but without success.

In fact it seems to be a bit out of date, and there were obviously some changes in cocos2d-html5 folder organization since it was written.

I'm pretty sure you can just take the `template` project provided in cocos2d-html5 and easily integrate the `circlechain.js` in it.

You may also take a look at this more recent tutorial: http://2sa-studio.blogspot.com/2013/11/setup-cocos2d-html5-project.html

Comment: This is quite right, there was a folder called 'plateform' in cocos2d, with the jsloader.js, but it has been moved somewhere else.

Comment: You should start from the template project provided in cocos2d-html5 and just try to integrate the `circlechain.js` in it

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to follow a few tutorials(including official tutorial), but unfortunately they didn't work, eventually I had a very simple 'hello world' page based on this [tutorial](http://blog.gfdsa.net/2014/02/08/game/startcocos2d/) , hope it will be helpful for those complete beginners of cocos2d-html5.(doesn't need MAMP though)

folder structure:

`cocos2d (you can find this in official downloaded package, I am using v2.2.2)`
`external (you can find this in official downloaded package, I am using v2.2.2)`
`helloWorld`
`--starter.js`
`--index.html`
`--main.js`
`--src`
`----HelloScene.js`

#### index.html

```
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="1000px" height="700px"></canvas>  
    <script src="starter.js"></script>
```

#### starter.js

```
(function(){
var d = document;
    //basic config of cocos2d
var c = {
    COCOS2D_DEBUG:2,
    showFPS:true,
    frameRate:60,
    renderMode:0,
    tag:'gameCanvas',
    engineDir:'../cocos2d/',
            // the scene we are going to activate, cocos2d game is built with scenes, which can have multiple layers, for instance, background layer, sprite layer, score layer
    appFiles:[
        'src/HelloScene.js'
    ]
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    var s = d.createElement("script");
            //add the js engine to the webpage
    s.src = c.engineDir + 'jsloader.js';
    d.body.appendChild(s);
    document.ccConfig = c;
    s.id = 'cocos2d-html5';
})
})()
```

#### main.js

```
var cocos2dApp = cc.Application.extend({
config:document['ccConfig'],
ctor:function(scene){
    this._super();
    this.startScene = scene;
    cc.COCOS2D_DEBUG = this.config['COCOS2D_DEBUG'];
    cc.initDebugSetting();
    cc.setup(this.config['tag']);
    cc.AppController.shareAppController().didFinishLaunchingWithOptions();
},

applicationDidFinishLaunching:function(){

    var director = cc.Director.getInstance();
    director.setDisplayStats(this.config['showFPS']);
    director.setAnimationInterval(1/this.config['frameRate']);
    director.runWithScene(new this.startScene);

    return true;
}
})
 // don't forget to initialize here
var myApp = new cocos2dApp(HelloScene);
```

#### HelloScene.js

```
var HelloLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
init:function(){
    this._super();

    var s = cc.Director.getInstance().getWinSize();
          //this layer is the background color
    var layer1 = cc.LayerColor.create(new cc.Color4B(0,0,0,255), 1280, 720);
          //set the position 
    layer1.setAnchorPoint(new cc.Point(0.5, 0.5));

    var helloLabel = cc.LabelTTF.create("hello world", "Arial", 60);
    helloLabel.setPosition(new cc.Point(s.width/2 , s.height/2));
    helloLabel.setColor(new cc.Color3B(0,255,0))
          //add the text to the previous layer1
    layer1.addChild(helloLabel);

    this.addChild(layer1);

    return this;
  }
})

var HelloScene = cc.Scene.extend({
  onEnter:function(){
    this._super();
    this.addChild(new HelloLayer().init());
  }
})
```